# a href link with java

Tags: java, android

my app retrieves data from a server online. If I insert the server like  Hello  in the app if you tap above do not lead anywhere. Why? This is the source

```
MyText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.art.tit);
        Text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.artic.text);
        String formattedText = db.getTesto();
        String formattedTitle = db.getTitolo();
        MyText.setText(Html.fromHtml(formattedTitle));
        Text.setText(Html.fromHtml(formattedText));
```

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html.  Linkify your text.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the sample for hyperlink:

```
MyText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.art.tit);
Text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.artic.text);
tv1.setLayoutParams(textOutLayoutParams);
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+ formattedText + "\">" + formattedTitle + "</a>"));
tv1.setClickable(true);
tv1.setMovementMethod (LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
dialogLayout.addView(tv1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working using the following code :

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setLayoutParams(textOutLayoutParams);
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+ l.getRightString() + "\">" + l.getLeftString() + "</a>"));
tv1.setClickable(true);
tv1.setMovementMethod (LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
dialogLayout.addView(tv1);
```

`l.getRightString()` - contains a url like: `http:\www.google.com` 
 `l.getLeftString()`       - contains text for the url like: `"Go to Google"`

**RESULTS:** Text "Go to Google" on my dialog with blue color and underlined, and on clicking it the browser opens up and shows the respective page.
On returning/Exiting the browser it again comes to the app from the state where it had left.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In android you can add link in two ways,
 - In XML design `android:autoLink="web"` for textview it will take you to the web browser onclick
 - If you want to add in the code you can add like

`TextView yourTextview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteview);
yourTextview.setText(youURL link);
Linkify.addLinks(yourTextview, Linkify.ALL);`

thanks.